# How to call ng-model in my script (I'm using ng-repeat for items)

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-modal

I have data in my database as item and item.cell as output in my xml
what I need is: If I have no checked data, I will click the button and confirm modal will show that says: please check one item, else it will show the other modal.

```
<div class="list_number_sort first_number_list" ng-repeat="item in data1.users" >     

                    <div class="list_number">{{$index +1}}</div>      
                    <input type="checkbox" id ="{{item.cell}}" name="name" ng-model="item.checked" ng-click="del(item.checked)"/>
                    <label for="{{item.cell}}"><span></span></label>
                    <div class="sort_text" >
                      <span class="sort_title">{{item.cell}}</span>
                    </div> 
              </div>



<!Script-->
if ($scope.albumNameArray) {
                    $('#modal_modify_account ').modal('show');
                } else {
                    $('#modify_select_allert').modal('show');
                }
            };  


            $scope.del = function(item) {
                $scope.albumNameArray = [];
                   angular.forEach( $scope.data1.users, function(item){
                     if (item.checked) $scope.albumNameArray.push(item.cell);
                   });
                  }
```

Comment: where do you want ng-model in the script?

Comment: Im newbie in angular thats why I dont know how to ask this but this is what I want in my project; 1. I have ng-repeat item for my checkbox, I will click my checkbox then click my button to show success modal else if i didnt checked any checkbox then click my button, it will show "please check one checkbox" modal.